# How to use property values in postinstall scripts during Maven build

Tags: maven

I am using `rpm-maven-plugin` to create `rpm`s. I have used properties with filter to replace the properties values in scripts:

```
<mapping>
  <directory>${config.path}</directory>
  <sources>
     <source>
       <location>${resources.path}/etc/test.xml</location>
       <filter>true</filter>
     </source>
  </sources>
</mapping>
```

In the above piece of code the properties are getting replaced during Maven build because of filter attribute. Similarly I am having `postinstallscrtiplet` tag:

```
<postinstallScriptlet>
   <scriptFile>src/rpm/postinstall</scriptFile>
   <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
</postinstallScriptlet>
```

How to replace the property value in postinstall scripts since there is no filter attribute. Is there any way to replace the property value inside postinstall, preremove scripts?

Comment: use maven-replacer-plugin. Example: https://gist.github.com/4n3w/3365657

Comment: one way of using the properties is through definestatement. Is there any other way?